# Effects of element.classList methods on reflow

Tags: javascript, dom

Does `element.classList.remove('className')` cause a reflow if the `className` does not exist?

Same for other `element.classList` methods?

Comment: What do you mean by _"cause a reflow"_ ?

Comment: if a class on an element is changed, the CSS will reapply rules. What if it doesn't change, but the method is called?

Comment: What do you mean by _"What if it doesn't change, but the method is called"_ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList
An implementation for classList is given there and it has these line:

```
if (updated) {
    this._updateClassName();
}
```

So, looking at it, it does not look like it causes a reflow :D

Comment: @IndustrialControlFreak dont mention it :D